# Unable to change the Text style from ref setNativeProps

Tags: javascript, react-native, dom, react-hooks, ref

I wanted to change some of the style of my  component when some of my textInput in focus,

I use expo 34.0.0

there are 2 methods, i have tried: using ref and using state, both have problems which i need to understand.

by far, The style in `<TextInput>` is working as expected when I change them thru `onFocus` function from TextInput.

but when I tryo to change style in `<Text>` by including  or using button to change `refTitle` with the same method by calling `refTitle.current.setNativeProps()` is not working, everytime i try to change the Text style it's only return refTitle.current.setNativeProps is undefined.

```
const refTitle = useRef(null)
const refUser = useRef(null)

return (
    <Card>
        <Margin>
            <Text ref={ refTitle } style={ styles.title }>as</Text>
            <TextInput
                ref={ refUser }
                style={ [styles.input] }
                onSubmitEditing={ () => refPassword.current.focus() }
                onFocus={ () => refUser.current.setNativeProps({ style: { borderColor: FOCUS_COLOR } }) }
                onBlur={ () => refUser.current.setNativeProps({ style: { borderColor: BLUR_COLOR } }) }
            />
```

so if I change the onFocus in textInput with

```
const handleFocus = () => {
        refTitle.current.setNativeProps({ style: { color: FOCUS_COLOR } })
        refUser.current.setNativeProps({ style: { borderColor: FOCUS_COLOR } })
    }
```

I dont know why it doesnt work, been searching but guide tell me it's okay, is it a bug in the recent React Native ?

2nd. I did use state, which more simply but there's a kind of bug i dont understand.

I simply use onFocus function to setState new color, ...everytime I click the textInput, it does changes the color... but it's not really focusing, i have to click again to make it fully focused ( the keyboard shows up and indicator begins to ticking)

Answer (score 0):

You have to use reference to use setNativeProps

```
 <TextInput
 ref={ref => {this.referencedeTF = ref;
          }}
/>
  this.referencedeTF.setNativeProps({
        borderColor: "red",
        borderWidth: 1
      });
```

You are using the reference wrong way.

Comment: I did, because i was using useRef... but i fixed my problem already... turns out i forgot my `<Text>` was not native from react-native package... thanks for answer anyway

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i was using different `<Text>` and not from react-native... solved it, but i still confused if using state forced me to click twice to trigger the focus while the 1st press already change the color, perhaps because of the text wasnt natively from react-native